# How to understand prettier parsing error better

Tags: reactjs, eslint, react-testing-library, prettier

All,
In the RTL test case, while running, I got the below error.

89:12  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ";"  prettier/prettier

But, in line 89, there is no comma.

```js
await act(async () => {  // <-- Line 89
    user.click(closeButton);
});
```

How to understand this error better.

Thanks.

Comment: is there an unterminated line above line 89?

Comment: Can you show a few lines of code before line 89?

Answer (score 1):

As it seems there is no comma in line 89. I believe this error you're getting is an incompatibility between the parser option and the code.  According to [prettier doc](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#parser) it automatically infers the parser from the input file path, so you shouldn’t have to change this setting.

**1 -** re-install `prettier`

**2 -** If you use **ESLint**, install [eslint-config-prettier](https://github.com/prettier/eslint-config-prettier#installation) to make ESLint and Prettier play nice with each other